# Two-term asymptotic approximation for roots of an equation

Tags: asymptotics, roots, perturbation-theory

Find a two-term asymptotic expansion, for $\varepsilon \to 0$, of each solution $x$ of
\begin{equation}
x^{2+\varepsilon} = \frac{1}{x+2\varepsilon},\qquad (x > 0)
\end{equation}
My approach:
First rewriting the equation we get:
\begin{align}
x^{2+\varepsilon}(x+2\varepsilon)-1 &= 0,\qquad (x > 0) \\
x^{3+\varepsilon}+2\varepsilon x^{2+\varepsilon}-1 &= 0,\qquad (x>0)
\end{align}
Using $x = \mu X(\varepsilon)$, dominant balance and find $\mu = \varepsilon$. This yields
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon^{3+\varepsilon}X^{3+\varepsilon}+2\varepsilon^{3+\varepsilon}X^{2+\varepsilon}-1 = 0
\end{equation}
From this point I don't know how to proceed.